# How to limit textfield characters upto 10 and avoid whitespaces using UITextField Custom class?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How can I limit text field characters up to 10 and avoid white spaces using UITextField Custom class?

This is my current code.

```
import UIKit

class PinTextField: UITextField , UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if (string == " ") {
            return false
        }
        
        return true
        
    }
       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's modify your function to be like this

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (string == " ") {
        return false
    }
    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }
    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)

    return (updatedText.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).count <= 10)
}
```

Comment: You mean that you want to create your own custom UITextField and apply this rule?

Comment: Sure, you can, and one thing more you should create and variable called maxLength (Int) & `allowWhiteSpace` (Bool) to make your TextField more flexible. And the logic of `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {}` is implemented in where you handle delegate of it as normal

Comment: but when i assign this class to a textfield.Nothing happens..i even printing something..but it's not called at all

Comment: Ah, you need to implement the delegate in where your textfield is located in. For example: `MainViewController` contains `PinTextField` then you should implement delegate of `PinTextField` inside `MainViewController`

`class MainViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
      textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { ... }
}`

Comment: if i should implement the delegate in view controller.. then what's the role of custom class here?

Comment: Your custom class allows you to config to allow enter whitespace or not and the maxLength

Comment: I fixed it by adding self.delegate = self inside awakeFromNib...thank you for your sincere answers bro...my upvotes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Never forget to add self.delegate = self inside awakeFromNib if you are using delegates inside a custom class.

I think this will be helpful to people's facing the same problem.